# xterm is not working on RHEL 7.2

Tags: rhel, display, xterm

xterm is throwing below error on RHEL 7.2:

```
$ xterm &


[1] 21638
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
[1]+  Exit 1                  xterm
[/RHEL/Packages]


$ rpm -qa | grep -i xterm
xterm-295-3.el7.x86_64
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: `rpm -V xterm` says?

Comment: @Ignacio: nothing

Comment: try to remove it and install it again

Comment: try to remove it and install it again

Answer (score 1):

short: don't run the application as root

long:

The message tells you what's wrong.  The usual way to get this message is by logging in (as your normal, non-privileged user) and using **`su`** or **`sudo`** to switch to the **`root`** user.

The message (and check) was added in 1997 (it  appeared first as a patch to XFree86 at the end of June as a followup to discussion in May, and two weeks later in X11R6.3).

Before then, **`root`** could connect to your X session and run any program that you (as **`root`**) chose.  Unfortunately, many of the programs that were likely to be used weren't secure.  (This is still the state for almost all of the desktop applications).

The X library making the check does this after seeing that it's the **`root`** user and then removing environment variables (such as **`DISPLAY`**) which might tempt you into falling into that morass of unsecured applications.

Some systems allow the **`root`** user to log into a desktop session; for those most immediately-accessible applications have been selected to keep things relatively safe.  Some don't do that.

Now... in Red Hat 7, `xterm` is not installed set-uid or set-gid.  set-uid to root was used 20 years ago to open the BSD-style pseudo-terminals, and set-gid was used to update utmp.  Both of those went away quite a while ago.  You can see that by doing

```
ls -l /usr/bin/xterm
```

If there's a set-uid or root user permission to be found, the place to start looking is at the shell from which you're running xterm.

Comment: The `$` indicates that it's being run as a normal user, versus `#` for root.

Comment: He *could* have chmod'd the program.  Just as likely, running with a prompt set to '$'.  Take your pick.

Comment: Right, but `rpm -V xterm` returned nothing, which means that they haven't been tampered with.